# Set Questa Sim Double-Click Editor

Tags: questasim

I am trying to get Questa Sim-64 10.7a to open .sv files in Notepad++ when I double-click in the project window. I set the editor command to use Notepad++, so when I use the edit command in the Questa Sim console window it uses Notepad++. That also sets Notepad++ as the editor that is used when I select File-->Open in External Editor in the Quest Sim editor, but that means I have to open the file in the default editor, then open it in my preferred external editor.

How do I set my Questa Sim project to open the file in Notepad++ when I double-click on the file in the project window?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what I did, but suddenly it is working as expected. That is, double-clicking a file in the project opens it in Notepad++.

I tried restarting Questa Sim, and it still didn't work as expected. All of a sudden, without even restarting, it just works.

edit: This morning it is not working again, although I haven't changed anything. That is, it is opening in the default editor. Unless I'm missing something, I think this feature is just flaky.

edit edit: OK, I discovered a work around. Whenever I add an existing file, the editor defaults back to the Questa Editor. If I open any .sv file from Windows Explorer (I have .sv files associated with Notepad++ in Windows), Questa starts using Notepad++ as expected. So, it's some goofy Questa Sim bug for sure.

Answer (score -1):

1. install  gvim or notepad++
2. after installation go to This PC
3. select any file save with .v or .sv extension file
4. select and open with  gvim or notepad++
5. set gvim or notepad++  as  a default editer for .v or .sv with gvim or
6. whenever you open the file in questa  will open with the default tool only

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).